# Android project problem

Tags: android, eclipse

[here](http://uploaded.to/file/ds1slp)

I uploaded my Android project made in Eclipse. The idea is that i have a service, which computes the sum of two random numbers. But when i press the OK Button, i don't see the result in that edit box... why? What i'm doing wrong? Please help

Thanks!

EDIT: The code:

//service class

```
 package service;

import java.util.Random;
import com.android.AplicatieSuma;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ServiciuSuma 
{   
    public ServiciuSuma() { }

    public int CalculateSum()
    {
        Random generator=new Random();
        int n=generator.nextInt();
        int m=generator.nextInt();
        return n+m;
    }
}
```

The Application class:

```
package com.android;
import android.app.*;
import service.*;

public class ApplicationSum extends Application {
    public ServiciuSuma service = new ServiciuSuma();
}
```

and the main Activity class:

```
package com.android;

import com.android.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class Activitate extends Activity  {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);  

        View btn_ok = findViewById(R.id.btn_ok);
        btn_ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
            {
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                    CalculeazaSuma();                   
                }
            });
    }


    private void CalculeazaSuma()
    {
        AplicatieSuma appState = ((AplicatieSuma)this.getApplication());
        EditText txt_amount = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_amount);
        txt_amount.setText(appState.service.CalculateSum());
        //BindData();
    }
}
```

So that edit text does not show the sum of the random generated numbers, by the service. What's wrong?

Thanks

EDIT:

the manifest xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.android"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0.1">
      <supports-screens
          android:largeScreens="true"
          android:normalScreens="true"
          android:smallScreens="true"
          android:anyDensity="true" />

    <application android:name="ApplicationSum" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".Activitate">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
</application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"  android:targetSdkVersion="7" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: You can expect more answers if you can post the code snippet here rather than uploading the project somewhere.

Comment: You need to post at least a code snippet. My crystal ball broke today.

Comment: Try using txt_amount.setText("Test string") in CalculeazaSuma() and see if the button activates that. That's one way to narrow down to either the EditText or the service not working.

Comment: Yes, as a string it worked, so in my Service class i did; public int CalculateSum()
    {
        Random generator=new Random();
        int n=generator.nextInt();
        int m=generator.nextInt();
       // return n+m;
       return "Test";
    }

And "Test" was returned. If i write "return n+m", i got an alert error "The application .... has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again". I think it's because that method returns an int.. however, i guess the number are generated, not? That code is correct. If yes, now, how to fix the error?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fix will work:

```
txt_amount.setText(String.valueOf(appState.service.CalculateSum()));
```

Without that you pass integer and android thinks it's an id of a resource to display. You should really use DDMS to identify such problems.

Answer (score 0):

Have you specified in manifest that you want ApplicationSum to be used as application class?

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application 
        android:name="com.android.ApplicationSum">
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
public String CalculateSum()
{
    Random generator=new Random();
    int n=generator.nextInt();
    int m=generator.nextInt();

    String sum = Integer.toString(n+m) ;

    Log.v("CalculateSum", "N+M = " + sum);

    return sum;
}
```

Comment: But first, how can ensure that those numbers are really generated, and how can i see them?

Comment: Check out the edit. If you don't know what the Log line means, search google for "adb logcat"

Comment: I still got that error.. "The application .... has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again". And in the Eclipse console i did not see anything regarding to that log..

Comment: Android devices/emulators don't output to console, you have to use "adb logcat'. Google it and see. It's very useful for tracking down exceptions and logging activity. Essentially, you type "adb logcat" into a command prompt and it's a live feed of log messages

Comment: Thanks for responses. Now please tell me which event should i use for the numeric keyboard from android emulator? So when i press any button (from letters, numbers), i should do something... but which event?
Thanks

Comment: This is an entirely different question. Please post it as a new question on the main page. Also, report back as to what happened with the current issue